# Levenberg-Marquardt Backpropagation faster

Tags: neural-networks

I'm finding an alternative to Matlab's trainlm because it's not coded for GPU and it takes long time but the only alternative I've found is the very expensive NeuroSolutions with NeuroSolutions Accellerator.Anyone know any open source alternative for NVIDIA CUDA GPU?

Thanks!

This question is related to automatic learning, because only those who are self-learning experts can know the right code I need, certainly not a generic programmer.

Comment: If you comfortable with python you can try neupy library. It has LM implemented in tensorflow which supports CPU and GPU backends. http://neupy.com/modules/generated/neupy.algorithms.LevenbergMarquardt.html

Comment: This question is related to automatic learning, because only those who are self-learning experts can know the right code I need, certainly not a generic programmer.

Comment: Although this may be controversial, I am persuaded by your argument that this is a question worth considering here.